# How does the Linux kernel detect Power over Ethernet (PoE)?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver, ethernet

I want to capture a signal in the kernel when it detects [Power over Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet#Two-_and_four-pair_Ethernet) is connected.

I don't have GPIOs to do this business.

I am working on the Atheros chipset-based access point. It has a Realtek RTL8363SB Ethernet module.  Is there a mechanism, interrupt, signal, or API in the kernel which detects from where it is getting power?

I have enabled `CONFIG_POWER_SUPPLY` while building kernel v 2.6.36.

Comment: Hi @Nachiket Jagade, we also work with POE boards, but the power supply detection implementation is from hardware. The Linux kernel does not distinguish between the power supply from PoE or an adapter. I think if you can ask some HW guys to do HW rework with some GPIO, you can detect such condition

Comment: thanks dien for feedback. I talked to H/W guys to implement new GPIOs.
actually H/W change is tedious task so thats why I was trying for S/W solution.any ways thanks